# Set default time in Flatpickr minus 1 month

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code which I use into React app.

```
<Flatpickr options={{
   enableTime: true,
   dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
 }}
 id="fromDate"
 value={dateFrom.getTime() === 0 ? '' : dateFrom}
 onChange={([date]) => {
 setDateFrom(date);
 }}
 />
```

How I can set the default time 1 month before the current time when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/), you can see that there is an option called "defaultDate", you can set it using [moment](https://momentjs.com/) like so:

```
const defaultDate = moment().add(-30, 'days').toDate();
// ...
<Flatpickr 
  // ...
  options={{
    defaultDate: defaultDate,
  // ...
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I tested the code but it's not working. Any idea why? I use Flatpickr from 'react-flatpickr'

Comment: Well, I checked the docs from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flatpickr#defaultValue, and it seems you have the defaultValue (as a string here), I read the official docs first, but this is a different package... Maybe this option works for you